# Appending to href and src to fix github root relative link error

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

After pushing my initial commit to github, I experienced a 404 error when trying to view the github page link. Realized it was due to having used root relative links for every href and src in my project. I need a way to append my github repository name to all href and src.

Any help is appreciated.

within my index.html file I have a script to append my repository name to all src and href - repository name is /Test_App

```
<script> 
$(function () {
    $('src').attr('src', '/Test_App').each();
    $('href').attr('href', '/Test_App').each();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: [`base` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)?

Comment: ```<base src="/Test_App" href="/Test_App"> ``` would this work?

Comment: base tag adds a part of a url to all the urls on the page, like links. if everything is say `/Test_App/stuff` then yes. the `href` attr is unesscary and not valid.

Comment: I would generally recommend against ever using the <base> tag. While it can help with some short-term problems, it's more likely to cause bigger headaches later on. I've posted an answer that you'll hopefully find to be a workable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's a frustrating problem, isn't it? The solution I use at the moment involves setting up a simple [Express](https://expressjs.com/) node server locally which redirects requests internally in a way that effectively ignores the `/${projectName}` part at the start of the GitHub Pages URL. With this approach, I can use the same paths as GitHub Pages does when I'm running the project locally and they will work correctly in both environments.

I've documented my approach in my [base project](https://github.com/cipscis/base-project) repository on GitHub, if you want to take a look. Here is the specific section in the readme about [GitHub Pages](https://github.com/cipscis/base-project#github-pages).

I'm using a `.env` file and the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) project to configure the project name, but you could just as easily hard-code it.

In case that link dies some day, here is the server code I'm using, which is the important part of this solution:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import express from 'express';
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT;
const projectName = process.env.PROJECT_NAME;

app.use(express.static('app'));

if (projectName) {
    // GitHub Pages publishes projects to <username>.github.io/<projectname>
    // This breaks root-relative URLs, so instead use "/projectname/path/" locally
    // and resolve it by redirecting it here to a root relative path.

    let ghPagesPathPattern = new RegExp(`^/${projectName}/`, 'i');
    app.get(ghPagesPathPattern, (req, res) => {
        let url = req.url.replace(ghPagesPathPattern, '/');
        url = `http://${req.headers.host}${url}`;

        res.redirect(url);
    });
}

app.listen(port, () => {});
console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: thank you for that detailed response, I appreciate it. I will take a look at the repo for any future projects I may need to use this for. The project I'm having this issue with is rather small, so I'm looking for something that may be a accomplished in jquery or just a simple script

Comment: Another approach I've used previously involved setting up my project with symbolic links, so if I looked for `/projectname/path/style.css` then it would go through my `projectname` symbolic link which leads back to the root, then it goes to `path/style.css` and finds the right file. The annoying bit is that GitHub Pages hosts static files, so if you want it to work there you'll have to play by its rules, and that means doing the awkward workaround stuff in your development environment.